# How do I stop canvas coordinates changing depending on canvas size?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my code example I have two setups. Using Tkinter and Turtle I first create an image of only 1000 x 1000 pixels and demonstrate that the origin is in the center of the image (not the usual top left) and the positive x direction is to the right, and positive y direction is up, like how we first learned the standard xy-plane.

However it seems there is some limit such that if a canvas is created above that limit, the coordinate system changes to the origin being in the top left corner but 'down' still being the negative y direction. The second half of my MRE places the origin of my 20000 x 20000 pixel canvas at (10000, -10000).

Is there a way to prevent this and does anyone know the cause? If there isn't a default setting of some kind I can pass through .configure() for the Tk.Canvas() object then how would I go about customizing world coordinates with Turtle to make sure the placement of the origin is independent of canvas size?

Here is my MRE:

```
import turtle
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None

def rectangle(t: turtle.RawTurtle, x0, y0, x1, y1, color: tuple):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x0,y0)
    t.pendown()
    t.color(color)
    t.begin_fill()
    t.goto(x1,y0)
    t.goto(x1,y1)
    t.goto(x0,y1)
    t.goto(x0,y0)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()

root = tk.Tk()

canw = 1000
canh = 1000

origin_x = 0
origin_y = 0

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas1.configure(width=canw, height=canh)
canvas1.config(bg='black')
canvas1.pack()

screen1 = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas1)

screen1.colormode(255)
screen1.tracer(0)

t1 = turtle.RawTurtle(screen1)

t1.speed(0)
t1.hideturtle()
t1.pensize(2)

print(t1.pos())

rectangle(t1, -canw, -canh, canw, canh, (0,0,0))

t1.pencolor((255,255,255))

t1.goto(0,0)
t1.pendown()
t1.circle(canw/2)
t1.penup()
t1.goto(0,0)
t1.pendown()
t1.goto(canw,0)
t1.penup()
t1.goto(0,0)
t1.pendown()
t1.goto(0,canh)
t1.penup()

screen1.update()

canvas1.postscript(file='new_canvas_test_1.eps', width=canw, height=canh)

img = Image.open('new_canvas_test_1.eps')
img.save('new_canvas_test_1.jpg')
img.close()

t1.clear()
screen1.clear()
canvas1.destroy()

# Brand new everything after this point except root Tk object

canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas2.configure(width=20000, height=20000)
canvas2.config(bg='black')
canvas2.pack()

screen2 = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas2)

screen2.colormode(255)
screen2.tracer(0)

t2 = turtle.RawTurtle(screen2)

t2.speed(0)
t2.hideturtle()
t2.pensize(2)

print(t2.pos())

rectangle(t2, -20000, -20000, 20000, 20000, (0,0,0))


t2.pencolor((255,255,255))

t2.goto(10000,-10000)
t2.pendown()
t2.circle(20000/4)
t2.penup()
t2.goto(0,-10000)
t2.pendown()
t2.goto(20000,-10000)
t2.penup()
t2.goto(10000,0)
t2.pendown()
t2.goto(10000,-20000)
t2.penup()

screen2.update()

canvas2.postscript(file='new_canvas_test_2.eps', width=20000, height=20000)

img = Image.open('new_canvas_test_2.eps')
img.save('new_canvas_test_2.jpg')
img.close()

t2.clear()
screen2.clear()
canvas2.destroy()
```

Here are the two images, the larger one scaled down:
[image: 1000x1000 image with origin coordinates at (0,0)]
[image: 20000x20000 image with origin coordinates at (10000,-10000)]

In order to get these images to be the same, as you can see I have to completely change the origin coordinates instead of simply creating the same image but on a bigger canvas.

Any thoughts and assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: first of as far as I know `turtle` uses a coordinate system that is centered while canvas uses a coordinate system that is flipped on the x axis and the center is in the top left corner. Second, why are you using turtle (because canvas has its own methods for drawing (creating) shapes, they can easily be adapted as you need) and what are you trying to draw?

Comment: The issue with using tkinter's drawing tools is that the amount of work I have to do to keep track of the orientation, and position of a 'pen' is many times more cumbersome in my experiences so far, than simply using Turtle which does that work in the background for me. I also ran into issues where lines did not match up in tkinter when creating random procedurally generated images like the ones I posted in a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68911808/customize-interact-with-how-lines-are-drawn-in-pils-imagedraw

Comment: I understand there could be a difference between the coordinates used by Turtle vs Tkinter's Canvas, but it seems odd to me that one takes over the other depending on the size of the canvas.

Comment: Btw `turtle` is built on top of `tkinter`. Also `tkinter.Canvas` doesn't have a pen or orientation. Also `turtle` was meant to be a library to teach new programmers the basics.

Comment: I know tkinter.Canvas doesn't have a pen or orientation, but what I'm trying to create requires me to keep track of those variables anyway. So using Canvas alone I'd have a current (x,y) I'd always need to update and keep track of and a theta that needed to be updated with each 'stroke'. This can get quite difficult when working with randomly changing shapes and curves. Which is why using turtle is a huge convenience. Despite it's simplicity and intended use, I've already used Turtle to make some pretty incredible random procedurally created images.